# Create stacking context for Leaflet map

Tags: css, leaflet, z-index

Can I somehow create new stacking context around my map so I dont have to provide big z-indexes to sidebars or other elements that will go over map.

Example: highest z-index for Leaflet map is 999 I think, can I somehow encapsulate map div and give it z-index 1 and expect that every other context with higher z-index will be on top of it.

Thanks.

*I forgot to add position:'relative', now it is working.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add position:'relative', now it is working.